# Using COUNT in a MYSQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli

Users can do posts and this posts can have comments and i want to get the number of comments made in all this users posts.

POSTS TABLE:

ID | CONTENT | FOTO | likes | genious | USER_ID | TIMEPOST | YOUVIDEO |

COMMENTS TABLE:

ID | USERS_ID | POSTS_ID | CONTENT | TIMECOMMENT |

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(comments.id) FROM comments INNER JOIN posts ON     
posts.id=comments.users_id WHERE posts.user_id=? ");

$stmt->bind_param('i',$_SESSION['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($comentarios);
$stmt->fetch();
$_SESSION['comentarios']=$comentarios;
```

Comment: Maybe because you're joining? Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Why INNER-join? Shouldn't it just be JOIN ?

Comment: Im joining so i can associate the number number of comments to all the posts that user made.
I tagged it with PDO because im using mysqli object oriented functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose, that you have `post_id` foreign key in comments table.

If you want to get the comments, made on this users posts, try this:

```
SELECT
    count(comments.id)
FROM
    comments
INNER JOIN
    `posts`
ON
    comments.post_id=posts.id
AND
    `posts`.user_id=?
```

Comment: This seems like the most direct method as the `JOIN` is not necessary to do the count.

Comment: I may be not explicit in my question, but i want all the comments made on this users posts

Comment: @ChristopherCosta Then improve your question plz: show the relevant tables data and structure and say, what do you want to get.

Comment: @ChristopherCosta Please, show the tables structure. It's hard to do what you need, without knowing it.

Comment: @user4035 are it more explicit ?